# Navigate Url, Hyperlink Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, hyperlink

I am trying to pass two parameters in my navigate URL to request them on my downloading.aspx file .

I always get this error ...

```
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

This is my code :

```
HL.NavigateUrl = String.Format("downloading.aspx?path={0}&file={1}" + GetTheCurrentDirectory(selectedNodeValue) + fri.Name);
```

I don't know why I get this error ... Can someone help me ?

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
HL.NavigateUrl = String.Format("downloading.aspx?path={0}&file={1}", GetTheCurrentDirectory(selectedNodeValue), fri.Name);
```

The parameters with String.Format should be separate parameters to the method call, or remove String.Format altogether:

```
HL.NavigateUrl = "downloading.aspx?path={0}&file={1}" + GetTheCurrentDirectory(selectedNodeValue) + fri.Name;
```